# Breeze.js and EF - Error loading entites

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I'm trying out the Hot Towel (Breeze) template for a new website (using AngularJS, Breeze 1.4.7, EF 6, WebApi2, breeze.angular.js) and have set it all up with NuGet. I have been able to query data, as long as I turn off server metadata on the data service:

```
var dataService = new breeze.dataService({
    serviceId: "breeze/job",
     hasServerMetadata: false
});
```

But when I try to make use of server metadata, I get the following error ('Job' is the entity type, and 'Models' is the namespace):

> [HT Error] Unable to get property Job:#Models' of undefined or null reference

I can hit the service URL for the metadata in Fiddler and see it ('~/breeze/job/metdata'). I can successfully call other queries that do not return an entity or `IQueryable` (e.g. that just return a count of entities). The $q promise is hitting the success callback, but the results are undefined.

The JobController:

```
[BreezeController]
public class JobController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<JobContext> cp = new EFContextProvider<JobContext>();

    public IQueryable<Job> GetJobs()
    {
            return cp.Context.Jobs;
    }
    // ...
```

If I put a breakpoint on the line `cp.Context.Jobs`, the Results View in the debugger tooltip over `Jobs` says `Children could not be evaluated`.

Thanks for any answers/pointers... (if any more info's needed, let me know. I'm not really sure what's relevant to the problem.)